# Why not able to get the 'Run on Server' option for JSF jsp page on eclipse, weblogic, JBossTools?

Tags: eclipse, jsf, weblogic, jboss-tools

I am trying to run a JSF 1.2 application created using Eclipse Ganemede and JBoss Tools on WebLogic 10.0 MP1

I have created a simple JSF helloworld application and have added a simple JSP. I have configured a weblogic domain and a server using the JBoss Tools plugin through eclipse. When I right click on the JSP file I can only see "Run Configurations..." options and NOT "Run on Server..". I do get this ('run on server') option when I right click on the application in the eclipse, but it doesn't run the

This is strange as in another JSF application on the same eclipse workspace, i am able to 'run on server' the JSP pages by right clicking on them.

Can anyone suggest a solution for this ?

Thanks.
Ankit

Answer (score 0):

Do you see any error log when you start the server associated to your JSF application (either in the eclipse Error log view or in the logs of the server)?

As illustrated by [this thread](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.webtools/msg12521.html):

> There are certain classes, identified by their package, that the server supplies which webapps aren't allowed to override.
>   If such classes are found in a jar in WEB-INF/lib, Tomcat deals with this by ignoring the offending jar.
>   Obviously, `javax.servlet` is one of those packages. Assuming `javax.servlet.jar` only contained `javax.servlet` classes, this shouldn't by itself cause your webapp to fail.
>
> I would start by removing this jar from the webapp since it is always wrong to have a jar like this in `WEB-INF/lib`.

Not much of a solution, but at least you can provide some more details/logs which may be enough for you to get a better grasp on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Can you add the project by dragging the project to the server ?

If not then it's not a WTP project of some reason and then no run-as will be available.

Answer (score 0):

There might be some error in web.xml.Even i faced the same issue after clearing the errors in web.xml ,i can able to see run-as option